# Adaptive Card - With Dynamic Variable with URL

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service, adaptive-cards

I am trying to create a dynamic variable with a url.

For example, I have a ticket number that I'm pulling, TKT41271823.

I'm able to display that number in the adaptive card, but lets say I have a URL attached to that ticket, like:

[www.gooogle.com/TKT41271823](http://www.gooogle.com/TKT41271823)

I can only create links using

```
{
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Check out [Adaptive Cards](https://adaptivecards.io)"
        }
```

Where "Adaptive Cards" is the clickable link.

I can hard code the value in it's place, like:

```
{
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Check out [TKT41271823](https://www.gooogle.com/TKT41271823)"
        }
```

But since I am getting support tickets dynamically it's always changing.

How can I insert a dynamic variable in this link, so when ever I call a specific ticket it displays the correct url.

For example:

```
{
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Check out [${ticket}](https://www.gooogle.com/TKT41271823)"
        }
```

When I try that, it displays the actual word in the adaptive card "${ticket}".

Comment: Please have a look at this doc-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/templating/sdk#usage 
Let us know if you have any query.

Comment: Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved with above suggestion or still looking for any help?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out the solution. We are using a platform called Amelia. Inside of it contained a specific service that was able to call to pass a variable through in place of the ticket number.

Comment: what exactly does that mean? and how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Without using Amelia (platform) or SDK, one can just utilize Adaptive Card Designer alone to modify the dynamic URL as follows:

```
{
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "[${TKT}](https://www.gooogle.com/${TKT})"
        }
```

Another example

```
 {
                  "type": "TextBlock",
                  "text": "[${$data.TKT}](https://google.com/Somewhere/?point=${$data.TKT})"
                }
```

It works the best to set the return property as a number, and no space between the return variable.  Make sure to include data binding "$data" as  in ColumnSet type or container elements.